# Display list values got by Javascript on JSP page

Tags: javascript, jsp, spring-mvc

I have this link on my test.jsp page

```
<a onclick="treeViewAjax('${searchDummyUrl}/view/${search.DummyNumber}/1')">View</a>
```

Now when I click on this then `treeViewAjax` ,A JavaScript method is being invoked as you can see in the link
Here is the `treeViewAjax` method

```
function treeViewAjax(Url){

        $.ajax(Url, function(data) {
            alert(data);
        });
    }
```

and at the same time my Spring controller's `searchDummyView` method invoked

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Dummy/searchDummy/view/{dummyNumber}/{dummyTypeId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
     List<Report> searchDummyView(ModelMap modelMap, @PathVariable("dummyNumber") Integer dummyNumber, @PathVariable("dummyTypeId") Integer dummyTypeId) {
        List<Report> reportList = new ArrayList<>();
        reportList.add(dummyService.readReport(dummyNumber, dummyTypeId));
        //modelMap.addAttribute("reportList", reportList);
        return reportList;
    }
```

Now when as Spring expert's can understand that I have used `@ResponseBody` annotation as to make to ajaxical request So it then again send response back to the requested URL.Now here again control is on my JS method `treeViewAjax` and when I alert the data then it show the list values perfectly.
 *Now I am stuck here that 
 How can I capture `reportList` returned by `searchDummyView` method on JSP page as well as How to iterate/Show its value on the JSP page using EL.* 
Any suggestions?
 **Note:** I have tried to show `reportList` like this but it didn't work for me

```
<c:choose>
            <c:when test="${reportList.size() > 0}">
<c:forEach items="${reportList}" var="list">
                                        //iterations over list but 
                                    </c:forEach>
...

... />
```

It did't display anything from list because of my condition `< 0` and I guess it is returning `0` size here OR not accessible here.(could be any reason)

Comment: Since you have commented `//modelMap.addAttribute("reportList", reportList);` this , the AJAX response is read in JS and there are no `reportList` in any of the scope.

Comment: @TheNewIdiot I dont think so.Read the question carefully.Op is using `@ResponseBody` due to apply ajax thing and in this case we always return the data neither add it to in modelmap

Comment: @freak Yes but then EL will never work , JSP is already in place he is just getting the data JSTL will not work in this case because JSTL will be processed at server side.

Answer (score 1):

This code will not work in your case :

```
<c:choose>
        <c:when test="${reportList.size() > 0}">
        <c:forEach items="${reportList}" var="list">
                     //iterations over list but 
        </c:forEach>
         ...

... />
```

Your JSTL and EL will be processed by the server and sent to the browser . But in your case the JSP is already rendered in the browser and you are firing a AJAX request which will give back some data . You are getting an AJAX response from server , not a full fledged response which the browser will try to render . To create a table with the data of AJAX response I guess there are two options :

1. Build the table using HTML and javascript dynamically once you get the AJAX response back.
2. Have a `<div>` inside your JSP and load another JSP with the table in that AJAX success.

Comment: I dont want to create it dynamically.Can you please expalin poit 2? I want to load div on the same JSP

Comment: If you use @ResponseBody to translate a object to JSON, then you can't use the JSP engine to generate a response. To leverage JSP ELs, you need to keep the action returning a View, and inside the view (JSP file), generate only the fragment that is relevant to your ReportList. Take a look at jQuery's load method: $("#someelement").load("url"), and use it instead of $.ajax.